# How to make mandatory based on pick list values

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I need to make mandatory Incorporation State/Province based on Incorporation Country. If Incorporation Country is Unites States or Canada The Incorporation State should be mandatory.

Comment: i need to add validation error for this if when become mandatory if that field is saved empty then one error should come

Answer (score 2):

You can use {Required="True"} attribute inside `<apex:inputField>`

Comment: But then it would always be required. The question asks for how to only make the field required when the country is the United States or Canada.

Comment: Try to use "apex:actionSupport" on change of picklist values which will call a method and try to send Boolean value "isBoolean" dynamically, i.e. Required= {!isBoolean}.
I think this can be your solution.

Comment: I didn't get you Kumar. Where can i use action support tag how to send boolean to that and how to pass in class also, Can you please make me understand please, I'm just learning writing visualforce pages

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Validation Rule`. You need it to return true when there should be an error, so its syntax should just check for either value, paired with a blank state.

```
AND(
    OR(
        Incorporation_Country_Text__c = "Unites States",
        Incorporation_Country_Text__c = "Canada"
    ),
    ISBLANK(Incorporation_State_Province_Text__c)
)
```

Comment: Hi the field is Not pick list field is text fields both are

Comment: That's not what your screenshot shows. Will update.

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you please give me suggestion on that

Comment: @chris I've updated my code with recommendation. Also if you do make the field required on the page instead, you can do so conditionally. That is: `required="{!OR(acct.Incorporation_Country_Text__c = "United States", acct.Incorporation_Country_Text__c = "Canada")}`.